# Retrofit парсинг json

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Работаю с API при помощи Retrofit. могут приходить данные двух типов: 
**Первый тип:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Второй тип**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в переменной cover. В ней может быть массив, а может быть boolean.

```
@SerializedName("cover")
private boolean cover;
```

две одноименных переменных даже разных типов быть не может

И соответственно выскакивает exception. Как решить такую проблему?

Comment: Сделать  cover `Object`, а затем приводить к `Boolean`/`HashMap` в зависимости от содержимого? Разбирать в разные переменные?

Comment: мне кажется, что это не `boolean`, а `null`. Бывает `"cover": true`?

Comment: Нет. это boolean. Ошибка вылетает именно мол: "boolean невозможно привести к типу cover"

Comment: ну вы в модели объявили его, как `boolean`, поэтому gson пытается впихнуть невпихуемое. Объявите, действительно, как `Object`, не `TypeAdapter` же писать...

Comment: Можно не Object, а JsonElement. Он сам расскажет isJsonObject или isJsonPrimitive... TypeAdapter тоже тема.